# Problems with the exceptions of the substitution derivative method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand `System.Exception` class and I got some problems with override function. I try to intercept exception of `DivideByZero` and Write my user message which I generate in function of derivative class from `System.Exception`. this is my code:

```
public class zeroDivision
{
    public void Deleter()
    {
        double z; int i = 0;
        try
        {
            z = 10 / i;
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, z);
        }
        catch (zeroMessage e) **<====problem here: DivideByZeroException**
        {
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, e.Message);
        }     
    }
}
public class zeroMessage : System.Exception <--here debugger even doesn't come
{        
    public override string Message
    {            
        get
        {
            string msg = base.Message;
            msg = "Деление на ноль ЗАПРЕЩЕНО!!!";    
            return msg;
        }            
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        zeroDivision zero = new zeroDivision();
        zero.Deleter();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

When I call: catch(zeroMessage e) - it unhandled, but if I call: catch(Exception e) - it works. Where is my fault? I don't understand

**-------------------------------**

**After some help of forum's masters, I remade this task with working functions. Maybe it will be useful for anybody:**

```
public class zeroDivision
{
    public void Deleter() //First way
    {
        double z; int i = 0;
        try
        {
            z = 10 / i;
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, z);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, "Делить на ноль НИЗЗЯ!!!");                
        }     
    }

    public double Deleter2(int a, int b) //Second way
    {            
        if (b == 0) throw new zeroMessage();
        return a / b;
    }

    public void prn(int i, int j) //Third way
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Deleter2(i, j));
        }
        catch (zeroMessage z)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
        }
    }

    public void firstDeleter() //Updated Yesterday's code - Forth way
    {
        double z; int i = 0;
        try
        {
            if (i == 0) throw new zeroMessage(); //!!!
            z = 10 / i;
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, z);
        }
        catch (zeroMessage e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, e.Message);
        }             
    }          

}

public class zeroMessage : System.Exception
{        
    public override string Message
    {            
        get
        {
            string msg = base.Message;
            msg = "Деление на ноль ЗАПРЕЩЕНО!!!";    
            return msg;
        }            
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        zeroDivision zero = new zeroDivision();
        zero.Deleter();

        try
        {
            double result = zero.Deleter2(10, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (zeroMessage z)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
        }

        zeroDivision zero1 = new zeroDivision();
        zero1.prn(10, 0);

        zeroDivision zero2 = new zeroDivision();
        zero2.firstDeleter();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to divide CLR throws the exception of type `DivideByZeroException`.

There is no way for CLR to know that you want to throw other exception.

But if you want to play with your new exception, you can do it like this:

```
public double Divide(int a, int b)
{
   if(b == 0) throw new zeroMessage();

   return a /b;
}
```

and use it:

```
try
{
   var result = Divide(10, 0);
}catch(zeroMessage exc)
{
  //here you will catch your exception.
}
```

However there is no sense in such exception, except education goals.

Comment: Yes, I use this code only for education. I tried to correct code with your suggestions: 'if (i == 0) throw new zeroMessage();' but compiler calls error in: 'throw new zeroMessage()' - An unhandled exception of type 'exception.zeroMessage' occurred

Comment: Did you wrap the Divide(10,0) call into try-catch block?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Everything in this string of code: **if (b == 0) throw new zeroMessage();** If I put in code it - everything works, if not - does not work. I tried to write code in different ways and everything works, but it is neccessary to use that string.

Comment: throw just throws the Exception of your type. So, you need to catch it. This is how exceptions work in C#. If you forget to catch it you will have this "An unhandled exception" error.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your code alone, nowhere do you actually **throw** `zeroMessage`.

If you want to intercept `DivideByZeroException` then that is what you have to do.

Get rid of the `zeroMessage` type, since it has no bearing on the results here, and change the catch code to this:

```
catch (DivideByZeroException e)
{
    ...
```

Note that the code in the runtime will throw exceptions *known* to the runtime at the time the runtime was compiled. It will not magically pick up that you want to substitute some exceptions for your own. The only way to catch a "x / 0" problem in your code is to catch the `DivideByZeroException`, not by inventing your own exception type.

Comment: The only way to catch a "x / 0" problem in your code is to catch the DivideByZeroException - I such thought, but I have found this example in the book and tried to do it by myself .. and got problems... catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, "Делить на ноль НИЗЗЯ!!!");                
            } - solve this task

Comment: I don't know how to respond to that. Was there a question in there? "I such thought", what does that even mean?

Comment: Sorry for my English. For previous message: I thought as much as you described in your answer, but the example was in the book and I decided to do it...and faced with problems. Of cause this string of code solves the problem: **catch (DivideByZeroException) { Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, "You cannt divide by ZERO!!!"); }**

Answer (score 0):

Both `DivideByZeroException` and your `zeroMessage` class derive from `System.Exception`. However that doesn´t mean that `DivideByZeroException` derives from `zeroMessage`!

What are you trying to achieve? Use `System.Exception` if you want to catch all possible exceptions, and use `DivideByZeroException` and the likes, when you are interested in a particular exception like:

```
double z; int i = 0;
try
{
    z = 10 / i;
    Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, z);
}
catch (DivideByZeroException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("N={0} i={1} Result={2}", 10, i, e.Message);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected error: ", e.Message);
}
```

Comment: this example from book Troelsen "C# and .NET". of cause in real life I would use something like **if (i==0) then continue;** or **catch(Exception e) {...Write("...");}***. But example...

Comment: @mit If you want to catch your own exception then it must be thrown. For example, the way Anton has explained